# Does this example warrant the use of public inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement a library where Class1 provides about five public methods Method1 to Method5. Class2 provides two methods - Methods6 and Method7. And Class3 provides one method - Method8. Now, for the end user, I want to expose methods from combination of these classes. E.g. If the end user instantiates a class called Class1Class2, they should have access to Method1 to Method7, if they instantiate a class called Class1Class3, they should have access to Method1 to Method5 and Method8.

There are 3 different approaches I could think of (please suggest any others as well):

1. Multiple inheritance: Keep each of Class1, Class2 and Class3 as it is. Then, create a new class Class1Class2 that publicly multiple inherits from Class1 and Class2. Similarly I can create a class Class1Class3 that publicly multiple inherits from Class1 and Class3.
2. Multi-level inheritance: I could derive Class2 from Class1, and call that Class1Class2. And Class3 from Class1 and call that Class1Class3. And if we need Class1Class2Class3, we inherit that class from Class2 and Class3, which have both derived from Class1. Here, we would use virtual inheritance to resolve the diamond problem. I don't expect to use Class2Class3, so that shouldn't be a problem here.
3. Composition: Keep each of Class1, Class2 and Class3 as it is. Create Class1Class2 that implements each of the methods Method1 to Method7 and internally delegate them to the objects of Class1 and Class2 accordingly. Similarly, a Class1Class3 would compose objects of Class1 and Class3. With this approach we need to provide implementations for all the methods and delegate them to the composed objects.

While "Composition over inheritance" guideline is generally great for loose coupling of classes, etc., in the above case, where we have to do code reuse from separate concrete implementations, Approach 1 or 2 seem like better options.

Comment: Have you looked at the Liscov substitution principle?  Proper inheritance has far less to do with code reuse than it does complying with substitutibilty.

Comment: Approach 1 looks much more feasible. Go for it.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes, but in this case, for option (2), Class2 that derives from Class1 does not alter any of the Class1's methods, hence technically IS-A Class1. So essentially, anytime user substitutes Class2 for Class1, nothing should break. Doesn't that satisfy LSP?

Comment: If a function takes a `Class1`, is it safe to pass a `Class1Class2`, `Class1Class3`, or `Class1Class2Class3` *for any operation that function performs*.  If so, LSP is met, and this is a suitable use of inheritance.

Comment: Two more ideas to regard: static polymorphism and CRTP.

Comment: There is no "right" answer (and, by the way, your question is opinion based and should be closed). You should express your question in terms of business logic, not in terms of "ClassN". But personally I would say that virtual inheritance is just a declaration of your failure to design properly, so avoid it.

Comment: Going by the [help/dont-ask]: *Negatives:* 1) Every answer is equally valid (unless you lie about your thoughts on this); 2) Your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers. *Positives:* 1) short answers are unlikely; 2) has an impartial tone. *Overall, I think this question is presented well, but still falls on the bad side of subjective. The question is possibly salvageable, but I don't have enough information to suggest how to salvage it. Maybe explain why these classes are considered equivalent to their methods instead of to their purposes?*

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't go into business logic due to confidentiality issues. And you're right, there's probably no right answer for the above question. But, I saw a lot of recommendations saying "public inheritance is evil", because it leads to high coupling, and hence, leading to extensibility nightmares. Hence, the question is trying to ask what are the exceptions to that rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want easy combination, you might use template as variant of your first proposal:

```
template <typename ... Bases>
struct Derived : Bases...
{
};

using Class1Class2 = Derived<Class1, Class2>;
using Class1Class2Class3 = Derived<Class1, Class2, Class3>;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works quite elegantly. Only follow up question is, is something like option 1 recommended, given the above use case. Or is public inheritance generally considered bad practice (as quite a few articles online seem to suggest)?

Comment: I agree that inheritance should not be the default choice, and prefer composition. But sometime, inheritance is more appropriate or convenient. up to you to do the (appropriate) trade of. (in present case, composition is verbose with some repetitions :/ inheritance is convenient... )

Answer (score 2):

You are only talking about code reuse here. I would think that's because you don't actually need nor want actual polymorphism. If this is indeed the case, then consider private inheritance and `using` to expose the parent methods.

For example:

```
class Class1Class2 : Class1, Class2 {
public:
    using Class1::Method1;
    // ...
    using Class2::Method6;
    // ...
};
```

Private inheritance, while technically being called inheritance, is very different from public inheritance, which itself is conceptually different from subtyping.

In C++ (and a lot of other languages that support OOP), public inheritance usually provides both subtyping and code reuse. However, it is entirely possible to derive a class with incorrect behavior in places that expect the parent class. This potentially undermines subtyping. It is also entirely possible to derive a class that does not reuse any of the implementation of the parent class. This potentially undermines code reuse.

Conceptually, subtyping is expressed by interface inheritance, while implementation inheritance is only one way to reuse code. The "composition over inheritance" saying, as far as I understand it, is about using other tools to reuse code because implementation inheritance often leads to bad code. However, there isn't really another way to achieve true subtyping than inheritance, so it may still be useful there<sup>1</sup>.

On the other hand, private inheritance is just an odd form of composition. It simply replaces the member with a private base class. An advantage of this is the ability to use `using` to easily expose the parts of that "member" you want to expose.

---

<sup>1</sup> I personally don't like either forms of (public) inheritance, prefering static polymorphism and compile-time duck typing. However, I can happily work with interface inheritance, whereas I usually stay far away from implementation inheritance.

Comment: You're right, I'm only referring to code reuse, subtyping is not applicable in the classes I have. So, would you say that private inheritance and `using` is a better alternative than public inheritance (option 1, for instance)? Can you please elaborate why?

Comment: @Chandan There, I elaborated.

Answer (score 1):

To make things more interesting you may employ CRTP. Here is an example:

```
template<typename Base>
class ClassA {
public:
    void MethodA1() {static_cast<Base*>(this)->MethodA1_Impl();}
    void MethodA2() {static_cast<Base*>(this)->MethodA2_Impl();}
};

template<typename Base>
class ClassB {
public:
    void MethodB1() {static_cast<Base*>(this)->MethodB1_Impl();}
    void MethodB2() {static_cast<Base*>(this)->MethodB2_Impl();}
};

template<typename Base>
class ClassC {
public:
    void MethodC1() {static_cast<Base*>(this)->MethodC1_Impl();}
    void MethodC2() {static_cast<Base*>(this)->MethodC2_Impl();}
};

class ClassABC: public ClassA<ClassABC>, public ClassB<ClassABC>, public ClassC<ClassABC> {
public:
    //void MethodA1_Impl();
    //void MethodA2_Impl();
    //void MethodB1_Impl();
    //void MethodB2_Impl();
    //void MethodC1_Impl();
    //void MethodC2_Impl();
};
```

You may uncomment and implement ANY subset of `MethodXY_Impl()`, and that would compile. The client code may call any method from `MethodXY()`. If there is no corresponding implementation - the compiler would produce an error.

Comment: I have implementations in different concrete classes because they are each responsible for that one thing. With your solution, you're moving all the implementation methods into class ABC.  Not sure how CRTP solution is solving the problem of reusing/exposing concrete implementation from 3 different classes.

Comment: @Chandan CRTP solves the issue of exposing different interfaces with no need to implement the whole set of methods. Moreover it avoids both virtual inheritance and dynamic polymorphism (both of them have significant drawbacks). Anyway, you haven't expressed your problem in the terms of business logic, so there is no right/wrong answer on your vague question.